# How many ways are there to assign six different jobs to five different employees if every employee is assigned at least one job?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

How many ways are there to assign six different jobs to five different employees if every employee is assigned at least one job?

The answer uses the Principle of Inclusion and Exclusion and is $1800$.

And this does not agrees with my intuition.

My intuition was that to first ensure that every employee is assigned at least a job, one job must be assigned to each employee initially, which then there will be one job left.

So, $\binom{6}{5} \cdot 5!$ many ways to do it.

The one job left can then be assigned to any of the five employees.

So $5$ ways to do it.

Finally, by rule of product, there is a total of $\binom{6}{5}\cdot 5!\cdot 5 = 3600$ ways.

And this does not agree with the model answer $1800$.

Where am I thinking wrong? Any help please.

Comment: You are double counting.  If you assign the first guy job $A$ and then later assign him job $E$ that;s the same as if you went in the other order.

Comment: I have thought of this. But when i first saw the question, this doesnt reach my mind. What should i do in general to avoid making such mistake?

Comment: It can be hard.  I always ask myself  "what symmetries are there in the situation?" .  Here, the fellow with jobs $(A,B)$ is the same as the fellow with jobs $(B,A)$.  You can avoid that by working with unordered assignments or by doing exactly what you did and then dividing by $2$ to kill the symmetry.

Comment: You appear to be missing as well the crucial detail that no job has more than one employee doing it.

Comment: @JMoravitz i guess it is a hidden assumption in the question. I wrote exactly what the question is.

Comment: To do it with unordered assignments:  First pick the fellow with $2$ jobs ($5$ choices).  then pick two jobs ($\binom 62=15$ choices), then permute the rest and assign ($4!=24$ choices).  So then the answer is $5\times 15\times 24 =1800$

Comment: Thanks for the help. I really got to beef up my intuition =/

Comment: No problem.  Intuition in these things is hard to come by.  One way to do it is to work with smaller sets (say, $2$ people, $3$ jobs).  Then you can list everything and check your procedure.

Comment: @lulu There is another solution, $5^6-4^6 \dbinom{5}{1} +3^6 \dbinom{5}{2}- 2^6 \dbinom{5}{3} +1^6 \dbinom{5}{4} = 1800$ , but i can't figure out how to get this solution. Please help.

Comment: Well, first take all the ways to assign the jobs, with no constraint.  That is $5^6$.  Now subtract those which only are assigned to four of the employees, now add back those which are only assigned to three of the employees, and so on.

Comment: @lulu What is the "Property" of set $A_i$ for $i=1,2,3,4,5$ used?

Comment: Well, not entirely sure what you mean.  I think you mean "only $i$ employees are given no jobs" (but then you need $i$ to include $0$).

Comment: i see the solution equation has the form $|S| - \sum_{1\leq i\leq 5} |A_i| + \sum_{1 \leq i < j \leq 5} |A_i \cap A_j| - ... - |A_1\cap A_2\cap A_3\cap A_4\cap A_5|$. Here, $S$ is the number of ways without constraint. I cant decipher how $A_i$ is defined in the solution equation.

Comment: @lulu I think $A_i$ is an assignment where Person $i$ is not given a job, for $i=1,2,3,4,5$. The last term of the solution $|A_1\cap A_2\cap A_3\cap A_4\cap A_5|$ vanishes because it is impossible that none of the $5$ person is assigned a job. Is that correct?

Comment: No, I don't think so.  The binomial coefficient shows us that we are looking at all possible subsets of the employees of the given size.

Comment: @lulu Hmm, if so, then there is something wrong with my counting. Because my counting agrees with the answer. $A_i$ contains the arrangements with the property $P_i$ : Employee $i$ is not given any job. Then $|A_i| = 4^6$ and there is $\binom{5}{1}$ ways to select the Employee $i$ from the 5 Employees. $A_i \cap A_j$ contains the arrangements with both properties $P_i$ and $P_j$, i.e. Employees $i$ and $j$ are not given any job. Then $|A_i\cap A_j| = 3^6$ and there is $\binom{5}{2}$ ways to select the Employees $i$ and $j$ from the 5 Employees.

Comment: The remaining terms follows the same argument, with the last term being $0$ as described in the above comment.

Comment: Well, maybe you have it right.  It's not the way I picture it, but there are lots of ways to think through the same question.  If you are in doubt, try a different collection (e.g. $4$ employees, $7$ jobs).

Comment: Okay, hopefully i can be better at counting with more exercises.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are counting the employee who receives two jobs twice, once for each way of designating one of his or her jobs as the job you designated as the additional job.

Notice that there are $\binom{6}{2}$ to select two jobs to give to one person.  There are $5$ ways to select a person to receive those jobs and $4!$ ways to assign the remaining jobs to the remaining $4$ people.  Hence, the number of permissible assignments is 
$$\binom{6}{2} \cdot 5 \cdot 4! = 1800$$